# Is it possible to make a specific method working only with a specific constructor?

Tags: java

I have a class called `User.java`

```
public class User {

    public User(Context context) {

    }

    public User() {

    }
    
    public void getUserId(){
        
    }
    
    public void getUserName(){
        
    }

}
```

If I create an object of user class then I can reach to all methods such as `getUserId` and `getUserName`

```
User user_1 = new User(this);
user_1.getUserId();
user_1.getUserName();   

User user_2 = new User();
user_2.getUserId();
user_2.getUserName();
```

The main question is can I get getUserName only if I called a constructor that has one parameter? But if I call a constructor that does not have a parameter then I can't get getUserName. Is it possible in Java?

Comment: That sounds like an XY Problem - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why? You might have User's in a list and then you wouldn't know which version of the class it has?

Comment: @UnholySheep I want if I create object and passed parameter then I can reach to getUserName like this : `new User(this).getUserName();` but if I create object without passing parameter then `getUserName()` should not showing.

Comment: @matt I've put User class here as an example only, Take a look at my previous reply

Comment: @Taha I am also using User as example. `User a = new User(this);` and `User b = new User();`. Now if you want to call a method `doSomething( User x){ ...}` you can call it with both a and b. Anybody using the method won't know that user a has the method and user b doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. But you could use interfaces to say for instance LimitedUser and FullUser

```
public interface LimitedUser {
  int userId();
}

public interface FullUser extends LimitedUser {
  String getUsername();
}
```

Then use factory methods on for instance the User implementation

```
public class User implements FullUser {

  private final int id;
  private final String username;
 
  private User(int id, String username) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
  }

  public static LimitedUser createLimitedUser(int id) {
    return new User(id, null);  
  }

  public static FullUser createFullUser(int id, String username) {
    return new User(id, username);
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to achieve (roughly) what you want.

The easy, but possibly annoying way is to throw an Exception whenever a "forbidden" method is called:

```
public String getUserName(){
  if (someRequiredContext == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("method not allowed!");
  }
  // do stuff
}
```

This "works", but doesn't help the user avoid calling those methods, since there's no easy way for them to know if they can call `getuserName` on a given `User` object.

The more involved version would be to have two classes (for example `User` and `UserWithContext`), but then you can't instantiate them the right way. But you could use [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead of constructors:

```
public abstract class User {
  User() { ... };

  public static User createUser() {
    return new BasicUser();
  };

  public static UserWithContext createUser(Context context) {
    return new UserWithContext(context);
  }

  public String getId() { ... }
}

class BasicUser extends User { // this class need not be public!
}

public class UserWithContext extends User {
  UserWithContext(Context context) { ... }
  
  public String getuserName() { ... };
}
```

This way the *type* will inform the users of your API which methods are allowed with a given `User` object.